# How can I calculate gradients of each element in a tensor using GradientTape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, gradienttape

I would like to calculate the gradient of each element in a tensor with respect to a list of watched tensors.

When I use GradientTape's `gradient()` on `y` directly, the resulting `dy_dx` has the dimension of my `x`. For example:

```
x = [ tf.constant(3.0), tf.constant(4.0), tf.constant(5.0) ]
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
    g.watch(x)
    y_as_list = [ x[0]*x[1]*x[2], x[0]*x[1]*x[2]*x[0] ]
    y_as_tensor = tf.stack(y_as_list, axis=0)

print("---------------------------")
print("x:", x)
print("y:", y_as_tensor)
print("y:", y_as_list)

dy_dx_from_tensor = g.gradient(y_as_tensor, x, unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO)
dy_dx_from_list = g.gradient(y_as_list, x, unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO)

print("---------------------------")
print("dy_dx_from_tensor:", dy_dx_from_tensor)
print("dy_dx_from_list:", dy_dx_from_list)
```

results in:

```
---------------------------
x: [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=4.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=5.0>]
y: tf.Tensor([ 60. 180.], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
y: [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=60.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=180.0>]
---------------------------
dy_dx_from_tensor: [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=140.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=60.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=48.0>]
dy_dx_from_list: [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=140.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=60.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=48.0>]
```

Note both the tensor and the list versions' result have the same dimension as the watched `x`.

When I try to call the tape's gradient method for each element, I get want I want for the list but for the tensor all gradients are zero:

```
dy_dx_from_tensor_elements = [ g.gradient(y_i, x, unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO) for y_i in y_as_tensor ]
dy_dx_from_list_elements = [ g.gradient(y_i, x, unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO) for y_i in y_as_list ]

print("---------------------------")
print("dy_dx_from_tensor_elements:", dy_dx_from_tensor_elements)
print("dy_dx_from_list_elements:", dy_dx_from_list_elements)
```

yeilds:

```
dy_dx_from_tensor_elements: [[<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>], [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>]]
dy_dx_from_list_elements: [[<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=20.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=15.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=12.0>], [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=120.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=45.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=36.0>]]
```

**The `dy_dx_from_list_elements` values are what I am looking for** but I would really like to be able to get them from the tensor because my real world model outputs the `y` values as a tensor.

Any suggestion to how I could generate gradients for every element in a tensor would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is coming from iterating over a tensor. A `tf.unstack` or similar operation might be running internally and all `tf` operations need to be within the scope of the gradient tape for them to be taken into account. Gradients will be calculated only for a tensor in relation to another tensor that was involved in its calculation. A couple of examples:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = [ tf.constant(3.0), tf.constant(4.0), tf.constant(5.0) ]
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
    g.watch(x)
    y_as_list = [ x[0]*x[1]*x[2], x[0]*x[1]*x[2]*x[0] ]
    y_as_tensor = tf.stack(y_as_list, axis=0)
    t = tf.unstack(y_as_tensor)


dy_dx_from_tensor_elements = [g.gradient(y_i, x, unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO) for y_i in t]
dy_dx_from_list_elements = [g.gradient(y_i, x, unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO) for y_i in y_as_list]

print("---------------------------")
print("dy_dx_from_tensor_elements:", dy_dx_from_tensor_elements)
print("dy_dx_from_list_elements:", dy_dx_from_list_elements)
```

```
---------------------------
dy_dx_from_tensor_elements: [[<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=20.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=15.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=12.0>], [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=120.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=45.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=36.0>]]
dy_dx_from_list_elements: [[<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=20.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=15.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=12.0>], [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=120.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=45.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=36.0>]]
```

The same applies when you for example use `tf.split`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = [ tf.constant(3.0), tf.constant(4.0), tf.constant(5.0) ]
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
    g.watch(x)
    y_as_list = [ x[0]*x[1]*x[2], x[0]*x[1]*x[2]*x[0] ]
    y_as_tensor = tf.stack(y_as_list, axis=0)
    t = tf.split(y_as_tensor, 2)
```

According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#getting_a_gradient_of_none):

> The tape can't record the gradient path if the calculation exits
> TensorFlow.

Also, `tf.stack` is generally not differentiable.

Comment: Ok thanks! So essentially, I'll have to do the splitting within the scope of the gradient tape.

Comment: @MortenGrum Yes exactly staying within the context is important.

Comment: @MortenGrum maybe also take a look at this: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#:~:text=Gradient%20tapes%20use%20memory%20to,pruned%20during%20the%20forward%20pass. for further details.